# Keyboard shorcut continuity from Mac to iPad

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, continuity

Io am trying the keyboard and mouse shareing (called Universal Control) between Mac and iPad. It’s a very useful feature but I can’t use Shortcuts like <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make second character on the keyboard or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to “select all” the text.

Is it my configuration or is it  an Apple limitation ?

Update:
Solution
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253744159 solution suggest by Tom Gewecke

```
On Your iPad:
Go to SETTINGS > Accessibility > Keyboards > HARDWARE KEYBOARDS > turn Full Keyboard Access to ON
** Also (on the same page), SOFTWARE KEYBOARD > toggle Show Lowercase Keys to ON
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I did some editing to your question to help make it clearer.  However, can you give more detail about using `Shift` for the “second character?”  What is happening and what do you expect to happen? When you say `Meta-A` do you mean `Command-A`?  Apple keyboards don’t have a key called `Meta`.

Comment: Hi thanks,
for example I had problem if I want do uppercase, @ o other symbol that need a combination of key to be insert.
The problem it's only when I share mouse and keyboard with Mac.

I also notice that if I move mouse on iPad, put focus on some input text and move back mouse on Mac (without change the focus) the keyboard works well

Comment: I thiink this problem with Universal Control has been discussed a lot in the Apple forums, see e.g.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253744159